# Reducing size of vectorized contourplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics

I would like to include a filled contour plot to a pdf document (for example a TeX document).
Currently I am using `pyplot`s [`contourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contourf#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf), and saving to `pdf` with `pyplot`s [`savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig). The problem with this is that the size of the plots becomes rather big as compared to a high resolution `png`.

One way to reduce the size is of course to reduce the number of levels in the plot, but too few levels gives a poor plot. I'm searching for a simple way to for example let the colors of the plot be saved as a png, with the axes, ticks etc. to be saved vectorized.

Comment: Can we see a typical plot ? Did you play with the nchunk parameter ?

Comment: The example given by @tom gives a typical plot. I did not play with the nchunck parameter, but for my purposes the chosen answer was sufficient. Best

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using the `Axes` option [`set_rasterization_zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_rasterization_zorder).

Anything with a `zorder` less than what you set that to be will be saved as rasterized graphics, even when saving to a vector format like `pdf`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(500,500)

# fig1 will save the contourf as a vector
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
ax1.contourf(data)
fig1.savefig('vector.pdf')

# fig2 will save the contourf as a raster
fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots(1)
ax2.contourf(data,zorder=-20)
ax2.set_rasterization_zorder(-10)
fig2.savefig('raster.pdf')

# Show the difference in file size. "os.stat().st_size" gives the file size in bytes.
print os.stat('vector.pdf').st_size
# 15998481
print os.stat('raster.pdf').st_size
# 1186334
```

You can see [this matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/misc/rasterization_demo.html) for more background info.

---

As pointed out by @tcaswell, to rasterise just one artist without having to affect its `zorder`, you can use `.set_rasterized`. However, this doesn't appear to be an option with `contourf`, so you would need to loop over the `PathCollections` created by `contourf` and `set_rasterized` on each of them. Something like this:

```
contours = ax.contourf(data)
for pathcoll in contours.collections:
    pathcoll.set_rasterized(True)
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks :D. For those who wonder: Artists with a lower `zorder` is drawn first, and artists with a lower value than that given in `set_rasterization_zorder`will be rasterized.

Comment: You can also use `set_rasterized` on an artist to rasterize it independent of the zorder.

Comment: @tcaswell: yes, but not all artists have that option. `contourf` returns a `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` instance, which doesn't have the option `set_rasterized`. You can loop over the `PathCollections` it creates in `ax.collections` and use `set_rasterized` on each of them, but I've found using `set_rasterization_zorder` tends to be a simpler option

Comment: Ah, that is QuadContourSet being a badly behaved container.