# Python matplotlib reducing the image resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a graph in matplotlib and when I save it, the image size is about 100MB because I am using `axs.fill_between()` which fills almost 1/3 of the image. I have tried reducing the dpi as follows but it did not change the image size.[image]

```
plt.savefig('plot.pdf', dpi=50)
```

Any idea how to overcome this problem and reduce and the image size to the point of few MBs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing the size of pdf figure file in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685495/reducing-the-size-of-pdf-figure-file-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you